# How to save ckeditor script in my Angular project instead of calling it dynamically?

Tags: angular, ckeditor

I'm using ckeditor in my Angular project. I load it dynamically every time the app is opened by adding it in a script tag in index.html file. However, it's taking a lot of time to load for some reason. Can I save the script in my project folder so that it can be accessed directly from there?

This is how I'm accessing it correctly in my index.html file.

```
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.9.2/full-all/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

I'm able to use ckeditor properly and all the functionality works fine. However, since it takes too long to load, I wanted to know if I can download it in one of my project folders and use it from there?

Comment: Check this [ckeditor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ckeditor)

Answer (score 0):

CKEditor 4 offers a native Angular integration through the CKEditor 4 Angular component. In your Angular project, install the `ckeditor4-angular` npm package.

`npm install --save ckeditor4-angular`

Then import `CKEditorModule` to your application.

```
import { CKEditorModule } from 'ckeditor4-angular';

@NgModule( {
    imports: [
        ...
        CKEditorModule,
        ...
    ],
    …
} )
```

You can check out this documentation for reference: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_angular.html